# Rectangle detection in noisy contours

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

I'm trying to build an algorithm that calculates the dimensions of slabs (in pixel units as of now). I tried masking, but there is no one HSV color range that will work for all the test cases, as the slabs are of varying colors. I tried Otsu thresholding as well but it didn't work quite well...

Now I'm trying my hand with canny edge detection. The original image, and the image after canny-edge look like this:[image] [image]

I used dilation to make the central region a uniform white region, and then used contour detection. I identified the contour having the maximum area as the contour of interest. The resulting contours are a bit noisy, because the canny edge detection also included some background stuff that was irrelevant:

[image] [image]

I used cv2.boundingRect() to estimate the height and width of the rectangle, but it keeps returning the height and width of the entire image. I presume this is because it works by calculating (max(x)-min(x),max(y)-min(y)) for each (x,y) in the contour, and in my case the resulting contour has some pixels touching the edges of the image, and so this calculation simply results in (image width, image height).

I am trying to get better images to work with, but assuming all images are like this only, i.e. have noisy contours, **what can be an alternate approach to detect the dimensions of the white rectangular region obtained after dilating?**

Answer (score 0):

To get the right points of the rectangle use this:

```
p = cv2.arcLength(cnt True)  # cnt is the rect Contours
appr = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt , 0.01 * p, True)  # appr contains the 4 points
# draw the rect
cv2.drawContours(img, [appr], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

The appr var contains the turning point of the rect. You still need to do some more cleaning to get better results, but `cv2.boundingRect()` is not a good solution for your case.

Comment: what do you mean by 'rect Contours', and how do I find them?

Comment: rec=rectangle, you need to use the same contours you used to draw the image above. you need to pick the bigger one because you want to take to one of the slabs

Comment: Ok, that works very well! But I'm a bit confused: where exactly in this snippet are you accounting for the fact that we need '4' points?

Comment: Can you also elaborate on how could I 'clean' this image more.. morphological operations?

Comment: Good question I don't know how, I just say that the `cv2.boundingRect()` is not good.

Comment: regarding the 4 points, if you will found a good filtering process, you will get 4 points of a rectangle (x,y).